# No writable dashboard found

Tags: azure-application-insights

In my Azure Application Insights, I'm attempting to save a chart to the AI dashboard. When I attempt to do so, I'm getting a strange error which can be seen below:

[image]

I certainly have a dashboard but not sure if it's "writable shared"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you publish the dashboard it is private to you and hence the message. You should click on share -> publish which produces a shareable dashboard. Once this is ready, pin to dashboard icon shows list of published dashboard which we can select to pin the result